# Visual Studio Installer, how can i select any folder using custom dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2012, setup-project

I have made a setup project using Visual Studio Installer. Now in this setup project I just want to have a custom dialog box which have one textbox and one button(BrowseButton), when I click this button a popup for selecting a folder in the target machine may appear.

In other words I want The "Browse For Folder button" or ""browser button" so that I may select any folder in the target machine. Once I select a folder the path should now come in the textbox. Because in the end I would like to save this path in the registry of the target machine.

I have Orca and I did tried to make this custom dialog using it but I am unable to do it.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one browse dialog in those setups, and that's for the main application folder, so there isn't a way to do this. A custom action won't help because they all run after the files are installed.

I don't know why and where you need to browse to, but in most case there is a simple default location (such as an application data folder or a shared folder) that works fine. This really helps during upgrades when the upgrade install may need to do something with that variable location, and any apps will always know where it is. It's easier for the user too.